# Trouble Implementing Jquery's .each() function on Paired Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

I thought I had implemented this .each function correctly, but as my script has become more complicated I've noticed some odd results.

My goal is to group pairs of items together and organize them based on their parent class.

Below is a simplified version of what I have

Script:

```
$(."pair").each(function(){
    alert($("div").val());
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class ="FirstGroup" id="A">
<div class="paired">Header Text</div>
<div class="paired">Body Text</div>
</div>
<div class ="FirstGroup" id="B">
<div class="paired">Header Text</div>
<div class="paired">Body Text</div>
</div>
<div class ="SecondGroup" id="C">
<div class="paired">Header Text</div>
<div class="paired">Body Text</div>
</div>
<div class ="SecondGroup" id="D">
<div class="paired">Header Text</div>
<div class="paired">Body Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".paired").each(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
})
```

5 problems

- syntax error with the `.` outside the quotation marks
- you're reselecting all divs instead of using the current `pair` element
- a `div` has no `value` property
- Missing the closing `)`
- Your elements have the class `paired` not `pair`

I can't really tell from your question what you intend with this code, but these are some starting points.

If you wanted to select the parent, then you'd do...

```
$(".paired").parent().each(...
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try:

```
$(".paired:first-child").each(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().html());
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jMRFt/)

Comment: You could do with `$(".paired").parent()` jQuery filters out the duplicate parents automatically http://jsfiddle.net/ruyGc/